Deploying A Single SSIS Package Using IsDeploymentWizard.exe In PowerShell for CI/CD
I have a powershell script using IsDeploymentWizard.exe to deploy a single SSIS package to SSISDB catalog.
# SSIS Deploy Script
#
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [String] $sourcepath,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [String] $destServerInstance,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [String] $destpath
)


IF (-not ($env:Path).Contains( "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn"))
 { $env:path = $env:path + ";C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn;" }

IsDeploymentWizard.exe /Silent /ModelType:Package /SourcePath:$sourcepath /Packages:"Mypackage.dtsx;" /DestinationServer:$destServerInstance /DestinationPath:$destpath

When I run it manually in PS command line, it works fine. For CI/CD, I created a release pipeline in Azure DevOps to execute the powershell script and deploy the single SSIS package. However, I am getting this error:
"Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application."
I think I have all the parameters I need for the executable and used the silent mode to not launch the GUI. Has anyone encountered this error before? Is there another parameter I'm missing that I should be including?

When you manually run on your machine, did you execute the exact same script without UserInteractive mode, or you also need to manually enter some parameters form the opened window of Integration Services Deployment Wizard?

@BrightRan-MSFT I provided the parameter values in the script and manually ran on PS command line. It didn't open the Integration Services Deployment Wizard window at all and it worked. Most of the time we want to only deploy one or two SSIS packages at a time and not the entire project.

Based on the error message, the command is trying to start the dialog box while the pipeline agent is not running as UserInteractive mode.
For your case, if you want to deploy a single SSIS project/package without UserInteractive mode, you can consider one of the following methods:

If you want to execute scripts to run the deployment using PowerShell, try the PowerShell scripts provided in the Microsoft official documentation "Deploy an SSIS project with PowerShell".

Since you want to run the deployment in Azure Pipelines, Microsoft also has published an Azure DevOps extension "SSIS DevOps Tools" which provides the pipeline tasks to build and deploy SSIS projects. This is the recommended way for SSIS in Azure Pipelines.

Install this extension to your Azure DevOps organization.


You can use the SSIS Build Task to build the SSIS projects.

If you have built the SSIS project, you can use the SSIS Deploy Task to deploy the output SSIS package of build.

You also can use the SSIS Catalog Configuration Task to configure the SSIS catalog.


For more details of this extension, you can see the documentation "SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) DevOps Tools Azure DevOps extension".




Thank you for your comment. We have used the SSIS DevOps Tools for deploying SSIS projects using Azure DevOps and this works for us. However, we will be only changing one or two SSIS packages in most cases and would like to be able to just deploy them without having to deploy the entire SSIS project.
I found a reference to using the IsDeploymentWizard in the command line from link.
It doesn't give any  information about the UserInteractive mode issue I encountered though.

@cenko, Try to set up a self-hosted agent on your own machine to run as interactive mode (see the documentation "Self-hosted Windows agents").
